# PHP - Data scraping

Tags: php, loops

I'm new to PHP Data scraping, I've looked over the other threads and I couldn't find what I needed.
I wanted to make a script that will constantly check a website if the infomation has changed, at the same time get the infomation.
For example:
google.com
I want to grab just the "Google Search" but at the same time, it will check every so often incase it has changed.
Cheers!

```
$html = file_get_contents( $url);

libxml_use_internal_errors( true);
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( $html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc);


$node = $xpath->query( '//div[@name="jsb"]')->item( 0);

echo $node->textContent;
```

Comment: you have added  code - great. but whats the issue with the code? are you saying it does not work? if so in what way?

Comment: And what is your problem and/or question?

Comment: @Dagon I get the following errors: Notice: Undefined variable: url in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 2

Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 2

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 6

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 12

Comment: error seems clear, where is `$url` ever defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) would be a great place to start and the also read up on [Cronjobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)

But show us what you got so far, so we can help you, we are not going to write the code for you.

## Edit:

the problem is with this line:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
```

where is the $url defined? it looks like it is empty, you can try and replace it with the website link so it looks like this.

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://domain.tld/page");
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing that, I'm blind.... But now I get this error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 12

Comment: that would be your xpath that is incorrect i would guess.